# MySQL always thinks ð and d are the same

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I'm currently trying to set up a database where I need to distinguish between ð and d but I can't find any working encoding. I've tried `utf8_bin`, `utf8_general_ci`, `utf8_unicode_ci`, `utf8mb4_0900_as_cs`, `utf8mb4_0900_bin`, `utf8mb4_is_0900_as_cs`, `utf16_bin`, `utf16_icelandic_ci`, and `utf16_unicode_ci`, but with each of those, MySQL thinks ð and d are the same, even with the icelandic encodings to my surprise. The weird thing is, the database on my private website uses `utf8_general_ci` and doesn't have this problem.

Edit: I got it working. For some reason changing the collation after creation of the table didn't use the new collation, even though it said it was using it. After creating a new table, while having the database collation set to for example `utf8mb_bin`, the new table could distinguish both letters.

Answer (score 1):

use BINARY or utf8mb4_bin see exmple

You can take every collation fro https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-mysql.html that has

> ```
> CREATE tABLE ab(te char(2) primary key) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE  utf8mb4_unicode_ci
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO ab VALUES('ð')
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO ab VALUES('d')
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT HEX(te), HEX ('d') FROM ab 
> #WHERE  BINARY(te) =  BINARY('d')
> ```
>
> ```
> HEX(te) | HEX ('d')
> :------ | :--------
> 64      | 64       
> C3B0    | 64
> ```

> ```
> CREATE tABLE ab1(te char(2) primary key) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE  utf8mb4_esperanto_ci
> #utf8mb4_german2_ci         
> #utf8mb4_icelandic_ci
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO ab1 VALUES('ð')
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO ab1 VALUES('d')
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE t1 (c CHAR(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO t1 VALUES('ð')
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE c = 'd'
> ```
>
> ```
> | c  |
> | :- |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=804d3953b40374bd49a39df36d99a21a)*

Comment: I already used utfmb4_bin and it didn't work

Comment: then use binary as i first suggested, as you can see in the example besides which version are you using

Comment: I need to have the characters in keys, so the first method wouldn't work for that. I got it fixed now (see Edit), even though I don't know why it doesn't work after changing.

Comment: i don't understand you see the hex value as long they are diffferent everything is ok. You only need to change your queries, but see first your sql mode if ot differs from sqlfiddle https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html

Comment: When using primary keys, the string have to be unique. So if the database thinks, two primary key strings are the same, it doesn't let me add the second one. Your first method works for everything except for when values need to be unique.

Comment: i added spme4 more that all work just fine, i still believe you have some strnge sql mode or you select always teh wrong collation

Answer (score 0):

[*This table*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8mb4_collations.html) shows that some collations distinguish between ð and d; some do not.

I see that `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` and `%_bin` (of course) treat them as different, but utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`and all`%0900%` collations treat them as equal.

'unicode' is Unicode version 4.0 (older); 'unicode_520' is 5.2; '0900' is 9.0 (newer)

A quick test for equality is

```
SELECT 'ð' = 'd' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```

That returns "1", meaning "equal" *for that collation*;

I guess the Unicode standards committee decided that they should be equal (after starting out with them unequal).

Any "bin" collation just checks the bits.  Since you say that utf8_bin did not distinguish between them, I suspect a test case error.  Please provide these:

- How the connection was done
- `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';
- `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'coll%';
- `SELECT col, HEX(col) ... -- to show exactly what was stored in your test tables.
- Whether you used `SET NAMES`
- The SQL used to perform the test.